# Finding string to address serial port dynamically

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, serial-port

I have an application developed in Java, and a second under development in Ruby on Rails, which require connecting to Arduino by serial communication.  While I can input a string based on my own computer to address the correct serial port, the string changes depending even on which USB port I use, which makes me think it would be better for the user to be able to select a valid serial port from one that is scanned from a list on their own computers, not one predefined by me.  Does anyone have a strategy I can use for allowing the user to scan their computer for all serial ports and select the correct one out of an array/list, either in Java or Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [List the ports](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/Listtheports.htm):

```
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier;

/**
 * List the ports.
 * 
 * @author Ian F. Darwin, http://www.darwinsys.com/
 * @version $Id: CommPortLister.java,v 1.4 2004/02/09 03:33:51 ian Exp $
 */
public class CommPortLister {

  /** Simple test program. */
  public static void main(String[] ap) {
    new CommPortLister().list();
  }

  /** Ask the Java Communications API * what ports it thinks it has. */
  protected void list() {
    // get list of ports available on this particular computer,
    // by calling static method in CommPortIdentifier.
    Enumeration pList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

    // Process the list.
    while (pList.hasMoreElements()) {
      CommPortIdentifier cpi = (CommPortIdentifier) pList.nextElement();
      System.out.print("Port " + cpi.getName() + " ");
      if (cpi.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
        System.out.println("is a Serial Port: " + cpi);
      } else if (cpi.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_PARALLEL) {
        System.out.println("is a Parallel Port: " + cpi);
      } else {
        System.out.println("is an Unknown Port: " + cpi);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This code is what I was looking for, however the Enumeration object does not populate with elements (the getPortIdentifiers method returns an empty Enumeration).  Any thoughts?

Comment: Hmm. Works here after a fashion. This  laptop claims to have two parallel ports ...:

$ java CommPortLister
Port LPT1 is a Parallel Port: javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier@11d50c0
Port LPT2 is a Parallel Port: javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier@e53b93
Error 2 opening registry key HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM

Comment: I used javaxcomm from (http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/sfnet_rcxtools/downloads/RCXTools/RCXTools%20v1.1/javaxcomm.zip/)

Comment: Try using [jssc](https://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/), with first example at (https://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/wiki/jSSC_examples)

Comment: This code worked once I added RXTXcomm.jar to the build path and switched the import from javax.io to gnu.io, thanks again for your help