# Accessing serial com port in windows8 through java

Tags: java

I want access serial com port in windows 8 but I'm unable to get com port using java but com port is showing in "Device Manager". Please do the needfull. Is any additional setting is required ?
I'm using the following code in windows8.

```
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier;
import javax.comm.SerialPortEvent;
import javax.comm.SerialPortEventListener;


public class SerialPortReading implements SerialPortEventListener {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

//
// Get an enumeration of all ports known to JavaComm
//
Enumeration portIdentifiers = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

CommPortIdentifier portId = null;  // will be set if port found
while (portIdentifiers.hasMoreElements())
{
    CommPortIdentifier pid = (CommPortIdentifier) portIdentifiers.nextElement();
if(pid.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) 
{
        System.out.println(pid.getName());

}

}

@Override
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent se) {
    System.out.println("ok");

}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644789/finding-string-to-address-serial-port-dynamically/24648168#comment38275800_24648168

Answer (score 0):

Java Communications API does not support Windows any more: [Oracle Download Page](https://github.com/Fazecast/jSerialComm). Use another library for example:
[JSerialComm](https://github.com/Fazecast/jSerialComm)